# Understand How Pandandable Works in this code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to the Python universe. I am learning to use language. I would like to learn how create a table space within an application. I would like to understand the following code (available at https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html), in particular some parts such as:

1 - Why did "Frame" enter parentheses: "TestApp (Frame)"?

2 - Why was **init** called after Frame: Frame .__ init __ (self)?

3 - I didn't understand the reason for the relationship: self.main = self.master.

4 - In app.mainloop (), why app? Usually we use the main window, but app is not window, before it is calling the class.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

class TestApp(Frame):
        """Basic test frame for the table"""
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            self.parent = parent
            Frame.__init__(self)
            self.main = self.master
            self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
            self.main.title('Table app')
            f = Frame(self.main)
            f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
            df = TableModel.getSampleData()
            self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df,
                                    showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
            pt.show()
            return

app = TestApp()
#launch the app
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***"I would like to learn how create a table"***: This is a bad pice of code, don't use it as template or to learn. There are couple problems here. Read [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759)

Comment: Please do not edit-war on this post. See the remarks I have made on your other two questions. If you still have queries about editing policy here, please ping me and wait for a discussion first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Why did "Frame" enter parentheses: "TestApp (Frame)"?* This way Python of declaring that the class `TestApp` inherits from the class `Frame`. If you are not familiar with Object-Oriented Programing: it means that `TestApp` is a new type of `Frame`, it will have all the attributes and functionalities of `Frame`, plus new things that can be implemented in the code block below it. Anyway, I would suggest you to read more on OOP, which is a large topic, to understand the above code.
2. *Why was init called after Frame: Frame .__ init __ (self)?* `Frame.__init__(self)` means it will call the initialization function of the `Frame` class. Since `TestApp` is a `Frame`, it inherits the `Frame` initialization function, and this is how you call such function.
3. *I didn't understand the reason for the relationship: self.main = self.master*, `self.master` is the parent Frame of the current app. This assignment assigns the master to the variable `main`
4. *In app.mainloop (), why app? Usually we use the main window, but app is not window, before it is calling the class.* `app` here is an instance of `TestApp`, which means it is also an instance of `Frame`